# Update SQL Datefield to add a week BUT keep same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a countdown script that works 100% successfully. It's pulling the data down from the database but I'm having a few issues with a cronjob script. I want it to add a week to the community_night date.

When I try adding to this, it keeps resetting the date to 0000-00-00 however I can see that the query should be working correctly.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connect));
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Community_Night");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$dbDate = $row['community_night'];

$date = strtotime($dbDate . ' + 1 week');
$setDate = date('d-m-Y',$date);

$sql = "UPDATE Community_Night SET community_night =" . $setDate;

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully: " . $sql;
    } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

the SQL column is set to DATE.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add - check out DATE_ADD

Comment: @user2182349 That's great and all but how do I apply the logic of updating the SQL query through a Cron?

Comment: `UPDATE Community_Night SET community_night = '$setDate'; `but see what others have said about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Community_Night SET community_night = community_night + INTERVAL 1 WEEK";
```

Bear in mind this will update all the rows in the table.